# The function $\frac{\sin(x^3+y^3)}{x^2+y^2}$ has all directional derivatives; is it differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider the function
$$f(x,y) = \frac {\sin(x^3+y^3)}{x^2+y^2}, \text{ for } (x,y)\neq (0,0),$$
with $f(0,0)=0$.

I have already proved that all directional derivatives exist.

Is the function differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If it is differentiable then   the derivative is necessarily  given by $A(x,y)=x+y$. (By looking at the partial derivatives).  To get a contradiction from  this consider $\frac {f(x,y)-A(x,y)} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}}=\frac {\sin (x^{3}+y^{3}) -(x+y)} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}}$.  I will let you show that $\frac {\sin (x^{3}+y^{3})}  {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}} \to 0$ and $\frac {x+y} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}} $does  not tend to $0$.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy, am I wrong or actually $$\frac{f(x,y)-A(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{\frac{\sin(x^3+y^3)}{x^2+y^2}-(x+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\\=\frac{\sin(x^3+y^3)}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\;\;?$$