# Differentiability on a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Check the differentiability of the function on $(0,0)$

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
\frac{sin(x^3+y^3)}{(x^2+y^2)}, (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
                        0, (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

I have already checked that f is continuous at $(0,0)$ and that the partial derivatives $f_x(0,0), f_y(0,0)$ exist and are equal to $1$.
The problem is that i cannot compute the
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-(xf_x(0,0)+yf_y(0,0))}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The function $\frac{\sin(x^3+y^3)}{x^2+y^2}$ has all directional derivatives; is it differentiable at $(0,0)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320839/the-function-frac-sinx3y3x2y2-has-all-directional-derivatives-is)